# Rewrite EVERY URL Resource of an Android WebView

Tags: android, url-rewriting, android-webview, webviewclient

I did not found an acceptable solution for rewriting all urls referenced in an WebView of an Android-App.

**I mean all urls!**
Not just those from HTTP-GET Methods. I also need to rewrite urls with  HTTP-POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD methods and urls inside Javascript(with all http methods).

Why I want to do this? I want to make an app, accessing intranet content from outside. Let's say intranet is located on `https://myintranet.com`

Let's say I have web resources `https://myintranet.com/resources/whatever.html`. If I am logged in my desktop-machine in the firm I can access the resource directly.

Now we want to go mobile. Therefore we do have a proxy, which supports https and basic authentication. We now accessing a resource with `https://myproxy.com/myInternalMapperToIntranet/resources/whatever.html`

What did I try:
I tried to set the Web view a `WebViewClient`overriding

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, String url)
```

[look here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) Unfortunately this only works for HTTP-GET requests but not for HTTP POST requests.

And a `WebViewClient` overriding

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)
```

same thing here, HTTP Posts mapped to a send Button or JavaScript do not provoking a call to one of those methods.

In my case the most easiest way would be, to get the HttpClient of the WebView, and intercepting all requests this urls wants to make and rewriting the url to the one with the Proxy-content.
I simply could define a regex and replace the Url. But it seems, this is not possible in Android. A Collegue did this on a iOS-App, but on Android it seems currently not possible. I found a possible solution @API 21 with:

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
```

the WebResourceRequests encapsulates the Http Method, so it smells for the possibility to intercept all httpMethods. Unfortunately I have to support API 17, and may not use this API.

I cant believe that this technical requirement cant be realized with standard android components. Please prove me the opposite! 
Does anybody knows alternatives? 
Doing the whole rewriting in the back-end for many simultaneous users is currently no alternative. It has to be done client-side on the App due performance issues.

TIA Luke

Comment: You could write your own HttpClient

Comment: i got confused so wat u need is use your same webpage on android also but you have issue with "https" ? sorry if i didnt get :)

Comment: @zgc7009 the HttpClient is deep down in the WebView. Could you purpose how to overwrite configure the client?

Comment: @Ahmad: No I have noissues with https, i have to change all urls that they are going over a proxy-server to the final location.

Comment: Are you using Volley?

Comment: @zgc7009 could you be a little more detailed? What would be the benefit of using volley in this scenario? all has to be finally shown in an Android WebView.

Comment: Didn't know if you had it in your project, you could have modified it's client and used it for your webview requests. Still can with apaches default client though.

Comment: @zgc7009: You get me wrong, I'm not searching for an httpFramework like volley. Im much more intrested how do you put this modified HttpClient to the Webview!? 
So that that everything will be run through that HttpClient? Could you place an example?

Comment: I misremembered the volley library, I thought the client stack utilized a custom HttpClient. I also was thinking you could set a custom client to your WebView but after some reading it seems I was wrong. I'll look into it more when I get some time, I'm interested myself.

Comment: any solutions ???? :s